# Bootstrap 3 drop down menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Mudalali | Sidadiya.lk</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="top-nav">
            <li><a href="#section-home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

        </ul>
        <?php echo $loginLink; ?>            
       <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Registe1r</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal">Login</a>-->
```

```
</div>
```

I placed this code in a seperate file not in index.php (i.e. root/PHP_INCLUDES/header.php).

I would be happy if someone can help me to find the error .

Thanks in advance

Comment: same with drop down menu buttons. modalbox and other things works fine.

Comment: Did you include a javascript library into your head section?

Comment: <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
Hi, I did add these links

Comment: Hm. Which browser are you using? also, do you have an example either live of in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is working fine please look at this fiddle and let me know if I am missing anything from your code or might you missed to put something...
http://www.bootply.com/130454

Comment: Hi the code is same, I wrapped the entire code inside this div
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></div>
Any idea ? mine still not working

Comment: Any browser specific issue? Or you may check in your firebug or console if you are missing anything or any error you can see.

Comment: Hi, I created a separate page with same code, it worked perfectly. that new page consist only Bootstrap classes. the page that I this doesn't work has some jquery plugins, can that be the issue ?

Comment: I think you must carefully check in your developer tools console that does it throws any error...because that only might be the issue you facing.